# jquery for loading images sequentially and keeping them?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, loader

I am looking for a simple bit of jquery that will load images in sequence.

So, I'm using the Document ready function, to 'trigger' it, however can't come up with how to '.fadein()' images one by one, in a gallery.

So, when the DOM is ready, IMG[1] will fade in, then, once this is done, IMG[2] will begin to fade in. If that makes sense.

I have tryed to use the '.queue()' function, but I simply can not use it in this instance.

I am open to any suggestions for different ideas (not jquery) :)

### Thanks

-Jim

Answer (score -2, accepted):

try this:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("img").hide();
        $("#1").fadeIn('slow', function() {
            $("#2").fadeIn('slow', function() {
                $("#3").fadeIn('slow', function() {
                    $("#4").fadeIn('slow', function() {
                        $("#5").fadeIn('slow');
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

html:

```
    <div>
    <img src="img.jpg" id="1" />
    <img src="img.jpg" id="2" />
    <img src="img.jpg" id="3" />
    <img src="img.jpg" id="4" />
    <img src="img.jpg" id="5" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

With fadein() you can also provide a callback function that is executed when the fadein is complete. so you can do something like this:

```
$('#img1').fadeIn('1000', function(){
    $('#img2').fadeIn('1000', function(){
            //go on as you like

     });
});
```

Of course this is only an example and you should create some more complex control method to fade all your images without writing thousands of nested functions. (if you provide your html maybe i can help you)

Answer (score 0):

This won't load and fade them in a specific order, but it's the simplest method of waiting for a loaded image.

http://jsbin.com/ayero6

Answer (score 0):

```
  $("img:first-child").fadein("fast", function () {
    $(this).next().fadein("fast", arguments.callee); 
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

This method would be more efficient than doing multiple callbacks to to the dom.

Each item inside the container would be faded in sequentially

$(document).ready(function() {

```
var faders = $('#container').children().hide();
    i = 0;

function awesomeFaders() {
    $(faders[i++]).delay(500).fadeIn(2000, arguments.callee);
};
awesomeFaders();
```

})

source: http://jc-designs.net/blog/2010/06/more-than-one-way-to-skin-a-jquery/